# How to install RetroPie over Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: retropie, raspbian-stretch

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and have been running the latest Raspbian (9.3 Stretch) from the Pi website. I tried following the instructions for using Git to get RetroPie and everything went fine until I tried to run the script (`sudo ./retropie-setup.sh`) I get the following error:

> Sorry - Raspbian/Debian Stretch (and newer) is not yet supported on the RPI.

Is this telling me that RetroPie is incompatible with my version? Is there a way to make it work? If not, can I uninstall all that I loaded with:

```
sudo apt-get install git lsb-release
cd
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this telling me that RetroPie is incompatible with my version?

Yes. [This is noted on their bug tracker](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/issues/2091); you'll have to use Raspbian Jessie instead. A recent [pull request](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/pull/2236) to their Git repository suggests that this is being worked on, but, for the moment, you're out of luck.

To get rid of `git` and `lsb-release`, the packages you installed, run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove git lsb-release
```

The command `git clone ...` will have created a directory called `RetroPie-Setup`. Just delete that as normal (for example with `rm`); essentially, all Git has done so far is download a repository into a directory on your Pi. Deleting that is all you need to do.

Comment: Perfect, everything is as it should be! I got another card for RetroPie and just "dual boot" when I want to switch. Thank you for the GIT education as well.

Answer (score 2):

**[As of March 20, 2018](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/issues/2091#issuecomment-374621296), RetroPie's install script should now support Raspbian Stretch.**

I (inadvertently) tested this for myself two days ago with a [manual install](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Manual-Installation). I ran the RetroPie setup script on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch, unaware of any compatibility conflicts. Afterwards, I was able to boot into RetroPie without issue.

---

To fix your installer, update your RetroPie setup script to the latest version:

```
cd
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup.git
```

Then re-run the setup script.

```
cd RetroPie-Setup
chmod +x retropie_setup.sh
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

---

For future readers looking for a full install guide: refer to the [RetroPie Manual Install guide](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Manual-Installation#install-retropie).

Answer (score 0):

As a confirmation, Retropie now works for me also not Raspbian Stretch!

I installed Jessie for Retropie because it didn't work on stretch back then.

Comment: Retropie works on **Raspbian Stretch**! Look at [RetroPie 4.4 is released](https://retropie.org.uk/2018/04/retropie-4-4-is-released/).